# Inequality involving finite sum and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, summation, exponential-function

I'm reading a proof where they use the following inequality:
$$\sum_{k=4}^n \frac{k^2}{n}(1-a)^{k+1}\le\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{n}\exp{(-ax)}$$
For $a>0$. I'm trying to show it.
So far I got
$$\sum_{k=4}^n \frac{k^2}{n}(1-a)^{k+1}\le \sum_{k=4}^n \frac{k^2}{n}\exp(-ak)$$
And $\frac{x^2}{n}\exp{(-ax)}$ is decreasing on $(2/a,\infty)$, so if $2/a\le 4$, I can see that the bound holds, but I'm not sure how to show it holds for general $a>0$

Comment: Did you compute lhs and rhs ? They are simple. Then look at their ratio

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I computed the integral, is there a nice way of calculating the sum explicitly?

Comment: @Snildt Did you check $a = 2, n = 5$?

Comment: @RiverLi Oh, I see - that's not great. 
In the proof where the inequality shows up, we strictly speaking only need it for all sufficiently large $n$, but this complicates it a bit.

Comment: @Snildt If $a = 2$, it seems the inequality is not true for any odd $n \ge 5$.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the sum, write
$$S_n=\sum_{k=4}^n \frac{k^2}{n}(1-a)^{k+1}=\frac {(1-a)^2}n\sum_{k=4}^n\big[k(k-1)+2k\big](1-a)^{k-1}$$ to face the usual derivatives of $\sum (1-a)^m$.

$$S_n=\frac{(1-a)^5}{a^3 n}\Big[(9 a^2+5 a+2 )-(1-a)^{n-3}(a^2 n^2+a (2 n-1)+2)\Big]$$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{n}\exp{(-ax)}\,dx=\frac{2}{a^3 n}$$ So, you need to show that
$$(1-a)^5 \Big[(9 a^2+5 a+2 )-(1-a)^{n-3}(a^2 n^2+a (2 n-1)+2)\Big]\leq 2$$ (which is true - Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot3D%5B-%28%28-1+%2B+a%29%5E5*%282+%2B+a*%285+%2B+9*a%29%29%29+%2B+%281+-+a%29%5E%282+%2B+n%29*%28-2+-+a*%28-1+%2B+n*%282+%2B+a*n%29%29%29-2%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C1%2F2%7D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D) for illustration)

Your turn !

Comment: I am able to show the last inequality, but I'm not quite sure how you derived that expression of $S_n$. What exactly do you mean by "to face the usual derivatives"? And should it not be $[k(k-1)+k]$ and not $[k(k-1)+2k]$ in your equation at the top?

Comment: @Snildt. Sorry for the typo.  Start counting from $k=0$ and remove the first terms.